# CouchDB Storage with Synchronization (Replication) in C#

Tags: c#, synchronization, nosql, client, couchdb

The following information is available about the CouchDB:

> CouchDB supports multiple DB replicas running in difference machines
>   and provide a mechanism to synchronize their data. This is useful in
>   occasionally connected applications (e.g. PDA). In this case, user can
>   work in a disconnected mode for a time period and store his data
>   changes locally. Later on when he connects back to his corporate
>   network, he can synchronize his changes back to his corporate DB.

I'd like to use CouchDB in my C# project that requires synchronization support (between local and corporate DB's).

How to store/retrieve data and, most importantly, implement proper synchronization support in a c#/CouchDB app?

There are many .NET clients for CouchDB, but none of them document the synchronization support.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a specific .Net client to perform synchronisation (replication is the correct CouchDB term).  In fact you can do it with the built in WebClient class as it's all just REST.  Most clients support raw HTTP/JSON queries which you should probably use to initiate any replication operation based on the examples set out here:

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_replicate_a_database

To be honest, I don't use a dedicated CouchDB client - I use RESTSharp: http://restsharp.org/

Comment: Hi Chris, can you post some real-world example of replication using WebClient? For example, I have a local database and a remote one. Need to sync them and display potential conflicts to the end user. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not writing the code for you - there are plenty of examples in the link I gave you on configuring replication and resolving conflicts.  You will have to extrapolate them yourself based on your particular requirements.

Comment: If you want me to award the bounty to your answer, please make sure to include a basic example of C# replication using RESTSharp or WebClient. The question is clearly about C#, but the page you linked to doesn't contain any C# info.

Comment: I don't care about the bounty.  It doesn't pay the bills.  We're not here to write the code for you.  If I was, I'd charge about 200GBP a post.  You should be able to piece together enough facts and information from the links above to do the work.  That's learning.